bootstrap icon not correctly rendered in firefox
While browsing the home page of bootstrap icons (https://icons.getbootstrap.com/), my Firefox (version: 115.9.1esr, 64-bit) displays some strange images, as shown below.

The above picture shows strange symbols where it should be "house" etc.  It only happens on the computer I am using to ask this question.
Correct icon rendering should be:


Yes it is the official bootstrap icon homepage: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

You should know not to tell me that down here. Tell the community in your question.
